# how to set auto div height from ul/li elements variable height

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to set my div to have an auto height depending on the height of ul - li - a elements. I want to create a simple horizontal div with background color but I see how I have no height for my div.
My li elements are links with icons and no text. This icons can-could have variable size.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

This is the html piece:

```
<div class="divmenu">
    <ul class="ul_tools">
        <li><a class="ico1" href="#" onclick="a_webgl_tools.zoom()" title="zoom"></a></li>
        <li><a class="ico2" href="#" onclick="a_webgl_tools.zoom()" title="zoom"></a></li>
    </ul>     
</div>
```

And its css :

```
.divmenuH {
    /* [disabled]margin: 25px  0 35px 15px; */
    background-color: #099;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}


.ul_tools {     }
.ul_tools li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;

}
.ul_tools li a {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 18px;height: 18px; 
    background-image: url(file:///D|/I_DESARROLLO/BIBLIO_ICONOS/Minimaloistas/mini.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 360px 360px /*20ICONS  18 x 18  */
}
.ul_tools li a.ico1 { background-position: 0px 0px;    }
.ul_tools li a.ico2 { background-position: -24px 0px;}
```

Comment: [this will be useful for you to read](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: Thanks Pete ! I'm going to review it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should fix your problem .

```
.ul_tools{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your experiencing a common error with nested floated block elements.  When the children of a parent are floated the parent often collapses and does not expand to the height of the children.

Add this to the parent.

```
.ul_tools {
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

You will also need to explicitly set the size of the `li` tags, since they will not be sized to fit the background image:

```
.ul_tools li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

specify float:left to .divmenuH

Answer (score 0):

Use This CSS

```
.divmenu{
    /* [disabled]margin: 25px  0 35px 15px; */
    background-color: #099;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;display:block;


}


.ul_tools {     }
.ul_tools li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block

}
.ul_tools li a {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 18px; 
    background-image: url(file:///D|/I_DESARROLLO/BIBLIO_ICONOS/Minimaloistas/mini.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 360px 360px /*20ICONS  18 x 18  */
}
.ul_tools li a.ico1 { background-position: 0px 0px;    }
.ul_tools li a.ico2 { background-position: -24px 0px;}
```